# Why does my sequelize model instance lose its id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got a node-based microservice built on top of postgres, using sequelize to perform queries. I've got a table of Pets, each with an `id` (uuid) and a `name` (string). And, I've got a function for fetching Pets from the database by name, which wraps the nasty-looking sequelize call:

```js
async function getPetByName( petName ) {
    const sqlzPetInstance = Database.Pet.findOne({
        where: { name: { [Sequelize.Op.iLike]: petName } }
    })

    if(!sqlzPetInstance) return undefined
    return sqlzPetInstance
}
```

It works great.

Later, to improve performance, I added some very short-lived caching to that function, like so:

```js
async function getPetByName( petName ) {
    if( ramCache.get(petName) ) return ramCache.get(petName)

    const sqlzPetInstance = await Database.Pet.findOne({ ... })
    if(!sqlzPetInstance) return undefined

    return ramCache.set(petName, sqlzPetInstance) // persists for 5 seconds
}
```

Now I've noticed that items served from the cache sometimes have their `id` prop removed! WTF?!

I've added logging, and discovered that the `ramCache` entry is still being located reliably, and the value is still an instance of the sqlz Pet model. All the other attributes on the model are still present, but `dataValues.id` is undefined. I also noticed that `_previousDataValues.id` has the correct value, which suggests to me this really is the model instance I want it to be, but modified for some reason.

What can explain this? Is this what I would see if callers who obtain the model mutate it by assigning to `id`? What can cause `_previousDataValues` and `dataValues` to diverge? Are there cool sqlz techniques I can use to catch the culprit (perhaps by defining custom setters that log or throw)?

---

EDIT: experimentation shows that I *can't* overwrite the `id` by assigning to it. That's cool, but now I'm pretty much out of ideas. If it's not some kind of irresponsible mutation (which I could protect against), then I can't think of any sqlz instance methods that would result in removing the id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a smoking gun, but I can describe the fix I wrote and the hypothesis that shaped it.

As I said, I was storing sequelize model instances in RAM:

```js
ramCache[ cacheKey ] = sqlzModelInstance
```

My hypothesis is that, by providing the same instance to every caller, I created a situation in which naughty callers could mutate the shared instance.

I never figured out how that mutation was happening. I proved through experimentation that I could not modify the `id` attribute by overwriting it:

```js
// this does not work
sqlzModelInstance.id = 'some-fake-id'
// unchanged
```

However, I read [a few things](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-reload) in the sqlz documentation that suggested that every instance retains some kind of invisible link to a central authority, and so there's the possibility of "spooky action at a distance."

So, to sever that link, I modified my caching system to store the raw data, rather than sqlz model instances, and to automatically re-hydrate that raw data upon retrieval.

Crudely:

```js
function saveInCache( cacheKey, sqlzModelInstance ) {
    cache[ cacheKey ] = sqlzModelInstance.get({ plain: true })
}

function getFromCache( cacheKey ) {
    let data = cache[ cacheKey ]
    if(!data) return undefined
    return MySqlzClass.build( data, { isNewRecord: false, raw: true } )
}
```

I never located the naughty caller -- and my general practice is to avoid mutating arguments, so it's unlikely any straightforward mutation is happening -- but the change I describe has fixed the easily-reproducible bug I was encountering. So, I think my hypothesis, vague as it is, is accurate.

---

I will refrain for a while from marking my answer as correct, in the hopes that someone can shed some more light on the problem.